# How to add "parts" in this example / redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How to add "parts" in this example
The problem is that I can't add a new object

My current reducer:

```
case "ADD_PART": {

      return {
        ...state,
        exercise: state.exercise.map((items, id) =>
          id === action.index ? items.parts[0].repeating : items
        ),
      };
    }
```

state before

[image]

```
{
    "exercise": [
        {
            "id": "60e07e588a2f1946f895475f",
            "name": "Wyciskanie sztangi",
            "image": "uploads\\2021-07-03T15-12-24.173Z-test.gif",
            "instruction": "Opierając tułów na ławce weź sztangielki",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "weight": 30,
                    "repeating": 10
                }
            ],
            "isOpen": true
        }
    ]
}
```

State after run reducer it changes the object to me

[image: state after run reducer]

```
{
    "exercise": [
        10
    ]
}
```

Comment: So what is going wrong in your code. If there is some error, please upload that. Also replace the image with the actual object

Comment: I added more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `id` iterator as the index of the element to pick from the `items` array.

```
id === action.index ? items[id].parts[0].repeating : items
```